# Parse Cloud Code runs on client side but not on server side

Tags: parse-platform, error-handling, runtime-error, parse-cloud-code

I wrote this large parse code for Parse Cloud Code that queries a row based on it's objectId. I wrote this all on my client-side and tested it with my localized html code. Everything works great! But, once I push it to the server and attempt to run I get Error 141 : "An error has occured"

Clearly, this is massively unhelpful. So, I broke the code down to the most basic call I can make, shown below:

```
function getCardPacks(request, response)
{
    var myTable = Parse.Object.extend("myTable");
    var query = new Parse.Query(myTable);
    query.get(request.params.tabId,
    {
        success:function(results)
        {
            response.success();
        },
        error:function(error)
        {
            response.error(error);
        }
    },function(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I still get the 141. I verified that the params I send this function are not null, but maybe they are getting undefined before they reach the function? I really have no idea what is wrong here.

Has this happened to anyone else? Or, is there a way I can get debug logs from the server end so I could determine if a val is null or find out where the script stops?

Comment: How are you testing the parse objects locally?

Comment: I have a main.js and an html page with buttons that send dummy values to the main. In main I have this 
`var module = require('cloud/myCode.js');`
 `function getTable_sum(request, response) {`
`module.getTable_Export(request, response); 
`}` 
`Parse.Cloud.define("getTable", getTable_sum);'

Comment: And for my transition from the html 

`function getTable_server()`
`{`
`var playerId = getInputValue("playerId");`
`var cardPackId = getInputValue("tableId");`
`var request = `
`{ `
`"params": `
`{`
`"playerId": playerId, `
`"cardPackId" : tableId,`
`}`
`};`
`Parse.Cloud.run("getTable", request, {`
`success:function(result)`
`{`
`response.success(result);`
`},`
`error: function(error)`
`{`
`console.log(error);`
`}`
`});`
`} `

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check the logs on Parse.com on your app. I'm confused what you are using cloud code for. If you are just querying a table, then you should be able to do that using the Parse javascript sdk. You can see how to set that up here. https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=syncup-staging#parse_data/web/existing